# Objective C MutableArray delete empty row

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, tableview

I have a problem with my tableview. When I tap the add button in my tableview it sends me to a textview where I can write a text. Then when I save it, it moves back to the tableview and create a new row with the text from the textview as title. If the textview is empty it saves it with no text, and create a row without a title in the table view.

I want to delete all rows without a title in the tableview. I save the text to a NSMutableArray named "savedText".

Here is some code I have tried:

```
if ([savedText containsObject:@""]) {
    savedText=nil;
}
```

and this:

```
if ([savedText isEqualToArray:@""]) {
    savedText=nil;
}
```

Nothing happens when I use this code.

Comment: Do you mean savedText contains both "" and "some texts" ? If not, you can just use [array count] == 0 to check if it is empty.

Comment: "When I tap the add button in my tableview it sends me to a textview where I can write a text. Then when I save it, it moves back to the tableview and create a new row with the text from the textview as title". You have complete control over this - stop it saving the cell if the text box is blank at the point where the user clicks back.

Answer (score 1):

Conny, one of us doesn't understand or is missing something here. It's probably me, but just to try to help out anyway.

As I understand it you're storing all the entered strings into the array named *savedText* and want to go through all the items in the array to check if they're empty and remove them from the array if they are. Is that correct?

GuybrushTheepwood is right in his comment, you could simply check before storing it in the array. If it's empty, just don't store it and you'll never have to make the processor work to remove it.

However, if you still want an algorithm for removing empty strings you'll need to try something else. Your first if block will get rid of the entire array if it contains something that's empty, and your second one should be giving a warning that the parameter isn't an NSArray*. Maybe your looking for something like this?

```
for (NSString* string in savedText) {
    if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [savedText removeObject:string];
    }
}
// Potentially more code here? Like reloading the tableview?
```

But that'll only remove it from the array, you'll need more than that to update the view.